# how to get base chart.yaml version from sub charts

Tags: charts, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an umbrella chart, it has a template for almost all subcharts deploymentConfig. how do i get the base chart version from the subchart.

maybe a solution will be to overwrite sub charts chart.yaml version but i tried to do that too without success.

i tried _helpers.tpl on the base chart
and to define on my _deployment-config.yaml on base chart

```
{{- define "bitcore.deployment" -}}
{{- $common := dict "Values" .Values.bitcore -}} 
{{- $noCommon := omit .Values "bitcore" -}} 
{{- $overrides := dict "Values" $noCommon -}} 
{{- $noValues := omit . "Values" -}} 
{{- with merge $noValues $overrides $common -}}
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
  labels:
    app: ## here i need base chart version ##
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    deploymentconfig: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  strategy:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
    recreateParams:
      timeoutSeconds: 600
    resources: {}
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
      labels:
        app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        deploymentconfig: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        test: required
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:xy"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.global.image.pullPolicy }}
        env:
          - name: BIT_CORE_RUNTIME_PROFILE
            value: '{{ required "Please provide runtime profile" .Values.global.runtimeProfile }}'
          - name: JAVA_OPTS
            value: '{{ required "Please provide Java Ops." .Values.global.javaOpts }}'
        livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: management/health
          port: 1489
        initialDelaySeconds: 30
        periodSeconds: 60
        timeoutSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 10
        name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1480
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: management/health
            port: 1489
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 10
        resources:
          {{- toYaml .Values.global.resources | nindent 12 }}
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /logs
            name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-volume-1
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-volume-1
        emptyDir: {}
  test: false
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

i excpected complicated version(7.0.0-snapshot-dev-872), but i got the subchart version 0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the `.Chart` of the superchart, anywhere, anyhow. After all, the subcharts are supposed to still be able to work as stand-alone.

The best you can do with helm 2 is to put the version in the `.Values.global` section.

In helm 2, you have to write it to the top-level `values.yaml` in the script that generates the version, because you can't have any code there. I believe in helm 3 it should be possible to generate values by script.

Comment: but that means i need to use --set flag on install and i dont want that..

Comment: @Matankila, you can write values for the subcharts in the values.yaml inside the main chart. But anyway, if you have to make your version-writing script update two files, you can make it update fifteen, i.e. just write the version in all the `Chart.yaml`s.

Comment: @Matankila… on the other hand, if you want to use the same version in all the subcharts, maybe it does not really make sense for them to be subcharts in the first place. There is no limit on the number of objects created from one chart and if they are not usefully usable separately—in which case having separate version makes sense—there is no advantage to having them as subcharts.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define  version values for the subcharts in the values.yaml file inside the main chart.

In my view there is no point to create multiple subchart with the same version, you can simply run them as ordinary charts. The main goal of Umbrella charts is to deploy more/large scale application with a lots of params - more often different. So if your subcharts have similar params like for eg. the same version, try to deploy them separately.

Useful documentation: [subcharts](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md), [charts-subcharts](https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/new-helm/helm-best-practices/#charts-and-sub-charts).

Useful article: [helm](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/creating-helm-charts/).